# How to find last user added in Linux?

Tags: linux, security, forensics

We had an attack on some of our Linux servers and we need to find if new users where added to the OS, I checked `/etc/passwd` and it doesn't seem to be something strange, but it doesn't show when each user was added to the system

How can I find the last users and their added date on a Linux server?

Comment: Have you checked auth.info (auth.log)?

Comment: yes... but the log doesn't show records more than 15 days old

Comment: If they used useradd to create the user that is where it would have been logged. If your system is not properly configured for longer retention of logs there is nothing that can be done after a server was compromised.

Comment: I believe this is covered in this other [Unix & Linux SE site question and answer thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140060/30848). One way to check user by user is `chage -l [username]` which checks the age between password changes. Meaning if the user was created X days ago then their password would be X age equivalent to the days ago it was created. For more info, check the [`chage` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have logs that go back to the date of the infection
(if you know that), then you can't do much except examining the dates
on the home folders of all the users. This wouldn't help if a virus
was using its home folder constantly during the infection period.

You may also check all the user accounts to see if some are unknown,
and erase them.

But even locating new user accounts wouldn't fix your problem or totally
eradicate a virus from your computer. My advice would be to totally
erase that server and rebuild from new. If you have an image of the
server that dates from before the infection (if you know that), then
you may return that image and use it as a starting-point.

Save all legitimate user data, if required, but not executable files
which may be compromised.